# Restart current application in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I deploy a web application on Jetty as a war.
Is there a way in which I can restart the currently running application on Jetty programatically?
Is there a Jetty configuration that can achieve this?

Comment: take a look at this -> http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Embedding%2BJetty, you might be able to do server.restart(); or something. Haven't tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 options.

1. Use JMX

   Try [enabling JMX](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/JMX) via the jetty-jmx libs and configuration.
   Then poking around the options for the contexts or deployers to see if you can use JMX to manage the deployed contexts
2. Create your own [Server bean](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server.html#addBean%28java.lang.Object%29) to manage the deployment / undeployment of the contexts
3. Create your own AppProvider, provided to the [DeploymentManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/DeploymentManager.html) to programmatically control the installed contexts.

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt at solving this problem: https://github.com/giuliano108/jetty-manager

```
sudo -u username jetty-manager

Usage:
  jetty-manager jvms
  jetty-manager webapps <jvm> [ <webappfilter> ]
  jetty-manager threads <jvm>
  jetty-manager stop <jvm> <webappfilter>
  jetty-manager start <jvm> <webappfilter>
  jetty-manager restart <jvm> <webappfilter>
  jetty-manager (-h | --help)

Commands:
  jvms           Show the running JVMs (PID, name)
  webapps        Show the webapps hosted by <jvm> and their state
  threads        Show the total number of threads in the <jvm>

Arguments:
  <jvm>          JVM PID or regexp (matched against the JVM name)
  <webappfilter> regexp matched against the context path (URL)

Options:
  -h --help     Show this screen
```